# How we can add filed as an attribute for an element for java REST API

Tags: java, rest, jersey, xml-nil

How we can add field as an attribute for an element for java REST API

My Java class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "rtml_application")
public class ApplicationsEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3256446889040622647L;
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    private String path;
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I want to generate xml response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rtml_application>
    <created_at type="datetime">2013-06-13T12:33:09.885+05:30</created_at>
    <id type="integer">9</id>
    <name type="string">REST TEST</name>
    <path nil="true"></path>
</rtml_application>
```

could any please help me out fix this problem using java annotation with jersey.

Comment: Can you be more clearer with your problem. Your title and your description are not making concrete sense . Not able to understand what is your problem.

Comment: Where are the 'type' attributes coming from; why do you need them?  Where did the value 'true' for 'nil' magically appear from?

Answer (score 0):

`@XmlAttribute` designates a field as an attribute, rather than an element